# Shopify - Issues with Jquery Function for displaying weight

Tags: jquery, shopify

how are you all today?

I need your help with coding on my product page (product.liquid). Need to display the weight + weight converted unit inside the variant radio buttons.

Jquery variant function on product.liquid:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    {% if product.available and product.variants.size >= 1 %}
    var product = {{product | json}};
    var layout = $('.product-page-area');
    if (product.variants.length >= 1) { //multiple variants
      for (var i = 0; i < product.variants.length; i++) {
        var variant = product.variants[i];
        var option = '<option value="' + variant.id + '">' + variant.title + '</option>';
        layout.find('form.product-form > select').append(option);
      }
      new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-selectors", {
        product: product,
        onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
        enableHistoryState: true
      });

      //start of quickview variant;
      var filePath = asset_url.substring(0, asset_url.lastIndexOf('/'));
      var assetUrl = asset_url.substring(0, asset_url.lastIndexOf('/'));
      var options = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < product.options.length; i++) {
        options += '<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="' + i + '">';
        options += '<div class="header">' + product.options[i] + ':</div>';
        options += '<div class="variant-items">';
        var is_color = false;
        var is_square = 'square';
        if (/Color|Colour/i.test(product.options[i])) {
          is_color = true;
        }
        if (swatch_color_type == '2') {
          is_color = false;
          is_square = '';
        }
        var optionValues = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < product.variants.length; j++) {
          var variant = product.variants[j];
          var value = variant.options[i];
          if(variant.featured_image && product_swatch_setting == '2') {
            var img = variant.featured_image.src.lastIndexOf(".");
            var vimg = variant.featured_image.src.slice(0, img) + "_50x50_crop_center" + variant.featured_image.src.slice(img);
          }
          var valueHandle = convertToSlug(value);
          var forText = 'swatch-' + i + '-' + valueHandle;
          if (optionValues.indexOf(value) < 0) {
            //not yet inserted
            options += '<div data-value="' + value + '" class="swatch-element '+is_square+' '+product_swatch_size+' '+(is_color ? "color" : "")+' ' + (is_color ? "color" : "") + valueHandle + (variant.available ? ' available ' : ' soldout ') + '">';
            
            if (is_color) {
              options += '<div class="tooltip">' + value + '</div>';
            }
            options += '<input id="' + forText + '" type="radio" name="option-' + i + '" value="' + value + '" ' + (j == 0 ? ' checked ' : '') + (variant.available ? '' : ' disabled') + ' />';

            if (is_color) {
              if(vimg && product_swatch_setting == '2') {
                options += '<label for="' + forText + '" class="swatch-image" style="overflow:hidden;"><img src="' + vimg + '" class="variant-image" style="max-width:100%;" /><img class="crossed-out" src="' + assetUrl + 'soldout.png" /></label>';
              }else{
                options += '<label for="' + forText + '" style="background-color: ' + valueHandle + '; background-image: url(' + filePath + valueHandle + '.png)"><img class="crossed-out" src="' + assetUrl + 'soldout.png" /></label>';
              }
            } else {
              options += '<label class="' + value + '" for="' + forText + '">' + '<span class="variant-button-top"></span>' + variant.weight + '<span class="variant-button-bottom"></span>' + '<img class="crossed-out" src="' + assetUrl + 'soldout.png" /></label>';
            }
            options += '</div>';
            if (variant.available) {
              $('.product-page-area .swatch[data-option-index="' + i + '"] .' + valueHandle).removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            optionValues.push(value);
          }
        }
        options += '</div>';
        options += '</div>';
      }
      if(swatch_color_type == '1' || swatch_color_type == '2') {
        layout.find('form.product-form .product-options > select').after(options);
        layout.find('.swatch :radio').change(function() {
          var optionIndex = $(this).closest('.swatch').attr('data-option-index');
          var optionValue = $(this).val();
          $(this)
          .closest('form')
          .find('.single-option-selector')
          .eq(optionIndex)
          .val(optionValue)
          .trigger('change');
        });
      }
  
      if (product.available) {
        Shopify.optionsMap = {};
        Shopify.linkOptionSelectors(product);
      }
      //end of quickview variant
    } else { //single variant
      layout.find('form.product-form .product-options > select').remove();
      var variant_field = '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + product.variants[0].id + '">';
      layout.find('form.product-form').append(variant_field);
    }
    {% endif %}
  });
```

On this line:

```
+ '<span class="variant-button-top"></span>' + variant.weight + '<span class="variant-button-bottom"></span>' +
```

I want to use: variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit

But it does not work. Even if i use: + variant.weight + variant.weight_unit +
It returns undefined.

I want to return the variant weight and the variant converted unit.

Can you give me a hand? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you need to assign the values to variables inside the loop and then use it inside JS code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Going to give it a try later :)

Comment: Let me know if the issue still there

Comment: Inside jquery, i've created a new variable:

var pweight = {{variant.weight | weight_with_unit | json}}

But when i call it, it still doesn't show the weight unit. Only the weight value.  Can't get my head around this.

Comment: `+ '<span class="variant-button-top"></span>' + variant.weight + ' '+variant.weight_unit+'<span class="variant-button-bottom"></span>' +`

Comment: try to replace with code line and then check

Comment: It returns undefined. I already got to that option before. The thing is i can't understand why it returns undefined

Comment: you need to check the JSON data of the product for this, weight is existed or not?

Comment: The product variants have weight. If i use liquid to get the data outside the Jquery it shows up. Inside the jquery i can get the weight to show. The weight unit doesn't no matter what i do.

Comment: If you are okay, can you please share the URL Of the product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the theme uses the  `{{product | json }}` to get the JSON data into javascript code, can sorry to say but JSON missed the variant weight unit and you can't get the same into the loop.

To overcome such a situation you need to get the JSON data using the product handle and this data contains the weight unit along with other data.

I hope this helps you other devs that have similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you've assigned a weight to a variant, use Liquid to display it. You can do simple math in Liquid. Skip all that Javascript nonsense and just use Liquid. It was made for this. There is no dynamic need for you to script this client-side, from what you describe here.

Comment: I’m not a developer. This is from a theme I bought. Unfortunately I only know html and css. JavaScript and other languages I usually pick pieces of code together until I achieve what I want. Need to expand my knowledge on this. Going to give it a try. I thought this might be a simple solution.

Comment: The simplest thing is to replace that 97 lines of ancient jQuery someone wrote 10 years ago, with a single line of Liquid that shows off your weight correctly. So if you are looking for simple, that is as simple as it gets.